# VB.NET MySqlDataAdapter.Fill takes almost 6-7 seconds

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I run a simple SELECT (noted below) in a stored procedure of a table that's around 1,500 rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `LoadCollectionItemProperty`(IN sId int(10))
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM itemproperty
WHERE itemid IN
    (SELECT itemid
    FROM collectionitem
    WHERE collectionid = sId AND removed ='0000-00-00 00:00:00');
END
```

This operation takes around 7 seconds. I inserted Breakpoints and used F11 to determine that upon MySqlAdapter.Fill is where the lag starts. Both my computer and the server hosting the MySQL database are NOT challenged spec wise. I'm guessing it's the query itself.

collectionitem holds the 2 foreign keys linking an itemproperty to a collection. we feed the sproc sId(PK of collection) so that the subquery returns all the itemids from a specific collection and then we use the itemid(PK) in itemproperty.

Is there any way to speed up the process?

**UPDATE**

My issue was entirely due to improper indexing. Once I learned which columns to index, everything is extremely smooth! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but it may not help much if your tables are missing indexes.

```
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM itemproperty i
WHERE exists
    (SELECT 1
    FROM collectionitem c
    WHERE collectionid = sId AND i.itemid = c.itemid AND removed ='0000-00-00 00:00:00');
END
```

Comment: I am uncertain as to what to index in the database

Comment: Generally, you'll want to [index fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) used in joins or filters. For your needs I'd index collectionid, itemproperty.itemid, collectionitem.itemid, and removed.

Answer (score 1):

Well given it's the query, (you should prove that by just running it at teh propmpt on the server)

Cut the query out of the sp and prefix it with Explain to see the query execution plan to confrm but some things stand out straight off.

```
SELECT *
FROM itemproperty
inner join collectionitem on collectionitem.itemid = itemproperty.itemid and removed ='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

to get rid of the subquery.

Is removed a date time, is it indexed?

Comment: removed is a timestamp, it is not indexed, if an item is removed a date appears instead of the 0000 so query doesn't pick it up. What should I index?

Comment: Agree with @kirrbs, if itemid is the primary key in your two tables, they are sorted and any serious delay would be doing a full scan for removed = whatever. Like I said copy the query out learn how explain works, do it before and after adding the indexes, start getting a snse of what it's saying.